# Tool for partial reverting a Git commit

Tags: text-editor, ide, git, command-line

A bug has been introduced in the last commit of a Git repository. Is there a tool for reverting chunks of this commit easily?

The tool would show the changes in the commit, and an option to revert them or not.

The tool could be an editor plugin, or a Git interface, or a git wrapper.

Comment: I use SVN but in that you can do a reverse merge which brings a previous version to the head, although I don't think there's a way to only do certain changes.
You can do a diff with previous versions though to see what changed and modify the files to include only the changes you need.

Comment: Resetting to the previous version and staging the changes in the last Git commit is possible as well. The best workflow I have for this scenario is resetting to the last commit staging the last commit's changes and opening Visual Studio Code. I'm wondering if is there better tools or workflows for this.